# how I can install Laravel 5 to the bottom of another website

Tags: laravel, installation

I tried to install to laravel 5 in website but I could not  do this.

```
 example.com(running another website)
```

I want to install laravel5 project to bottom of this webpage

```
in this way -> example.com/laravel5project
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create one directory name framework and upload all laravel project in it except public directory now you have to upload laravel index.php file from public in laravel5project and change paths in index.php at line number 22 and 36 it will start work directly from laravel5project